# How to count reactions of multiple messages?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and I want it to say multiple messages and react with a check to it, that I can do, but, I don't know how to make it count the check from the messages so I can make it select the top 5 messages with the most reactions, I can probably to all of it myself but I just need to know how to make it count the reactions from the messages. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have ID of those messages in an array.

```js
const allMessages = [
    "1000001",
    "1000002",
    "1000003",
    "1000004",
    "1000005"
];
```

So we'll run a loop through them

```js
for(let i = 0; i<= allMessages.length; i++){
    let messageID = allMessages[i];
}
```

Now we'll catch each message separately.
(I'll guess all the messages are in a channel catched as `Channel`)

```js
for(let i = 0; i<= allMessages.length; i++){
    let messageID = allMessages[i];
    let message = Channel.messages.cache.fetch(messageID);
}
```

Now we can count the reactions

```js
for(let i = 0; i<= allMessages.length; i++){
    let messageID = allMessages[i];
    let message = Channel.messages.cache.fetch(messageID);
    let count = message.reactions.cache.size;
}
```

And then we'll add them to a variable which will show all the counts together.
Let's put the code in a function for using `anync`

**Final code**

```js
const allMessages = [    //All the ID of messages you wanna count reactions.
    "1000001",
    "1000002",
    "1000003",
    "1000004",
    "1000005"
];
CountReactions = async (MessageArray) => {
    let totalCount = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<= MessageArray.length; i++){
        let messageID = MessageArray[i];
        let message = await Channel.messages.cache.fetch(messageID);
        let count = message.reactions.cache.size;
        totalCount += count;
    }
    console.log(totalCount);
    //In case
    //return(totalCount);
}
CountReactions(allMessages);
```

**If you want to count any specific emoji / reaction then do this**

```js
const allMessages = [    //All the ID of messages you wanna count reactions.
    "1000001",
    "1000002",
    "1000003",
    "1000004",
    "1000005"
];
CountReactions = async (MessageArray) => {
    let totalCount = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<= MessageArray.length; i++){
        let messageID = MessageArray[i];
        let message = await Channel.messages.cache.fetch(messageID);
        let count = message.reactions.cache.get('♥️').count;
        totalCount += count;
    }
    console.log(totalCount);
    //Just in case
    //return(totalCount);
}
CountReactions(allMessages);
```

Sorry if it's overcomplicating

Comment: Okay, so that's exactly what I needed... buuuuuuttttt, how do I make it do it after lets say... one hour?

Comment: Save the message ID in a database or something and put the code in a function. If you wanna automatically trigger it after one hour use `setTimeout`

Comment: Hmm.. TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Comment: Sorry forgot it was a promise so I had to await. I'll edit the code

Comment: You should use `Array#reduce` instead of a `for` loop. It's simpler and faster since all messages will be fetched at once instead of one after another